# Unable to connect to sites using IIS7 Manager

Tags: iis-7, remote-access, configuration

I'm a developer who has been assigned the task of managing and configuring a new IIS7 instance on a remote server.

My domain account has been added as to the local Administrators group on the box, but IIS7 has been configured to accept connections only from accounts with Windows credentials.

I've added my domain account to the IIS Manager Permissions for one of my sites, but I'm still unable to connect to either that site, the IIS instance or the server in general from my local machine.

There's obviously a missing element to the configuration of this setup but I don't know where to start looking.

The event logs on the IIS box show audit failures for my account when trying to connect remote via the IIS7 Manager tool on my local machine.

Suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause of the issue.

Under the server's Web Server (IIS) Roles, some System Services will be running automatically by default.  Unfortunately, the "Web Management Service" is not one of them.

Once I started this service, I was able to make the connection as expected.  More information can be [found here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/IIS/22_IIS7_-_Things_to_remember_when_using_Web_Management_Service.aspx).